# "United As One"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

A friend has argued that "**United**"/"**Unity**" itself already refers to individuals grouped together, and that for instance, these example sentences better fit in our case:

- United in love [*refers to what they are being united.*]
- United as brethren [*refers to the group in which they are joined/united to.*]

Sounds reasonable, but I don't know if there's something I missed in it's grammar that make's it right, if it is. Or maybe some historical reference.

Is the phrase "**United As One**" really correct?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with 'united as one'. It puts more emphasis on unity. Although 'united' implies say they are together but 'as one' says they look like one entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'as' in this case makes it a simile.

> **Simile** - a figure of speech involving the comparison of one thing with another thing of a different kind, used to make a description more emphatic or vivid

Meaning one thing is implied to be 'as' another (ie. As brave as a lion).

So while 'united' does indeed refer to a group of individuals, adding the 'as one' implies that they are no longer individuals but rather '*one entity*'.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem unnecessary to say both **united** and **as one**.

The term for this kind of usage is [tautology](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tautology) - the unnecessary and usually unintentional use of two words to express one meaning.

Comment: It's unintentional?

Comment: @Yawz, I don't know whether the person that wrote "United as one" intentionally made a tautology: you would have to ask them..